# greates number of baskets to put equal number of fruits

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

I am grade 6 student and trying this for the first time, so kindly excuse if I am making any mistakes.
I have this problem in my math book which I get a head around after lot of thinking, seeking help here
A grocery store clerk has to arrange 16 oranges, 20 apples and 24 pears in such a way that he puts equal number of Apples, oranges and Pears 
in each basket. What is the greatest number of baskets that can be made so that no fruits is left?

This problem is in GCF/LCM chapter, but I am not sure what method will apply to solve this problem, please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just edited my question, - A grocery store clerk has to arrange 16 oranges, 20 apples and 24 pears in such a way that he puts equal number of Apples, oranges and Pears in each basket.

Comment: I was going to ask whether you are aware that you have to be 13 years old or over to use this website, but I guess by now you are....

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

You will need to find the GCF of the three numbers. That is the greatest number of baskets that the clerk can have and still have the same number of each fruit in each basket.

-

Solution:
The GCF of 16, 20, and 24 is 4. Each of the 4 baskets will have 4 oranges, 5 apples, and 6 pears.

Comment: I earlier thought so, but the problem says each basket should have equal number of apples, oranges and pears in each basket, so if one basket has 4 oranges, it should have 4 apples and pears too.

Comment: I think, the way you understood the question may be the correct way of understanding, the way I understood it cannot be answered I guess.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is 4 baskets.Look for the highest number that all these given numbers (16, 20, and 24) can be divided by. They are all divisible by 4. In each of the 4 baskets, there will be 4 oranges, 5 apples, and 6 pears (these are the results of each division).